# Using Lucene when indexing I boost certain documents, but their score at search is still 1

Tags: lucene, lucene.net

I am trying to boost certain documents.  But they dont get boosted. Please tell me what I am missing. Thanks!

In my index code I have:

```
if (myCondition)  
{
   myDocument.SetBoost(1.1f);
}
myIndexWriter.AddDocument(document);
```

then in my search code I retrieve the collection of documents from the ScoreDocs object into myDocuments collection and:

```
    foreach (Lucene.Net.Documents.Document doc in myDocuments)
    {
        float tempboost = doc.GetBoost();
    }
```

and I place a breakpoint in the foreach clause to break if the tempboost is not 1. and the breakpoint is never hit.

What did I miss?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [javadoc](http://lucene.apache.org/java/2_3_1/api/org/apache/lucene/document/Document.html#getBoost()) of Lucene (Java version but same behaviors apply):

> public float getBoost()
>
> Returns, **at indexing time,** the boost factor as
> set by setBoost(float).
>
> **Note that once a document is indexed this value is no longer available
> from the index. At search time, for retrieved documents, this method
> always returns 1.** This however does not mean that the boost value set
> at indexing time was ignored - it was just combined with other
> indexing time factors and stored elsewhere, for better indexing and
> search performance.

note: for those of you who get NaN when retrieving the score please use the following line

searcher.SetDefaultFieldSortScoring(true,true);

Comment: Thanks! When indexing, I boost certain documents, but thy do not appear on the top of the list of retrieved documents. I looked at the score of those documents, and somehow, the score of the first document retrieved is always 0 and the score of the rest of them in the scoredocs is NaN.  Then I looked at the boost to try to figure out what was going on.

Comment: Apparently I do not understand the relationship between a boost of a document at index time and its score at retrieve time. I thought these would be correlated, and further, I thought I would get a wide range of scores in my scoredocs, not just 0 and NaN. If you can shed some light on this I would be grateful.

Comment: I've never experienced NaN scores in Lucene and I haven't been working with Lucene for some time. About nuances of scoring, I recommend this [somewhat lengthy document](http://lucene.apache.org/java/3_0_0/api/core/org/apache/lucene/search/Similarity.html) but it's worth reading it to understand what happens behind the scenes. You might also try to download Lucene source code, link it to your project instead of a compiled package, and then run your code in debug mode, but it's quite complicated to watch the run as Lucene's code is divided into many cooperating classes.

Comment: And boost at index time is correlated to the score at retrieve time; it's just multiplied with some other factors and then stored in a field in Lucene repo (for better speed), so it's impossible to get it back at retrieve time. See also [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7526720/possible-to-ignore-lucene-document-boost/7529502#7529502).